# adding a library for making an excel file

Tags: android, excel

there is a problem when I add a library to my dependencies . I wanna add this library to my dependencies to change the SQLdatabase to an excel file.please help me.

```
compile 'com.ajts.androidmads.SQLite2Excel:library:1.0.2')..
```

error massage:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(Power Network) 
from AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-38
is also present at [com.ajts.androidmads.SQLite2Excel:library:1.0.2] 
AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at 
AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-29:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what it tells you to do:

```
tools:replace="android:label"
```

in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in manifest

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.asguha.barcode_scanner" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

and tools:replace="android:label" in application

```
 <application
        tools:replace="android:label" ..
```